# Checking all checkboxes that match array items

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have the following HTML (its really JSX code for react, but its the same):

```
<div id="roles-checkboxes">
    <label id={role} key={index} ><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value={role.role} /> {role.role}</label>
    <label id={role} key={index} ><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value={role.role} /> {role.role}</label>       
</div>
```

I have an array that I pass into my function that contains all the `role` checkboxes that should be checked:

```
  checkRoleBoxes(roles){
    $('#roles-checkboxes').each(function(){
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), roles)){
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    })
```

I cannot seem to get the boxes to check despite my function finding matches, am I setting the checked property wrong? I have also tried `$(this).attr('checked', true);` with no luck.

Comment: Your use of `each()` on an `id` selector implies that you have multiple elements with the same `id` which is invalid, and would be the cause of your issue. Change the `id` on those checkboxes to a class.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He is not even selecting the input he is selecting the parent div

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector to be:

```
$('#roles-checkboxes input')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this:

```
 $('#roles-checkboxes').each();
```

Is simply iterating over the one div. Probably change it to:

```
 $('#roles-checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each();
```